# grails plugin to get gmail attachment

Tags: grails, plugins, gmail, attachment

I am working on a grails project and i need a plugin to extract an email attachment from a Gmail account.

My colleague said something about Java Mail API but i am not actually sure about how to integrate the api with grails.

Is there any other plugin or workaround to extract an email attachment from a gmail account?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While not specific to extracting attachments from GMail, the [Grails Routing plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/routing) would definitely be worth evaluating.  It integrates [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) into your Grails services and controllers and provides a very easy way to create routes.  You can then add the following dependency to your `grails-app/BuildConfig.groovy` file:

```
// replace x.x.x with version used by the Grails Routing plugin
runtime("org.apache.camel:camel-mail:x.x.x")
```

In the documentation for the Mail component you will an example of grabbing attachments from GMail and there is also this [blog entry by Mr Haki](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/04/use-apache-camel-plugin-in-grails.html) that shows an example using the older Grails Camel plugin (Routing plugin supercedes it).

While I haven't used Camel for this purpose, I have used it on a few projects and would recommend it as a possible solution.  It is a very powerful integration tool and can really make it very easy to do some pretty complicated things.